# Implement submenu in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a menu in my webApp and I wanna add a submenu.for implement that feature I need to attach click event to the `a` tag with `has-sub` class for every single menu. how can I achieve that?
I should add `(click)` event to the all of `a` tag. or there's better solution?

What should I put in javascript side of that component?

Thanks

```
<ul>
    <li><a>test</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="has-sub">test<icon name="plus" size="5"></icon></a>
      <div class="submenu">
        <ul class="container">
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: If willing to use a third party library, try http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/megamenu

Comment: @JSNinja I don't wanna use third party lib.

Comment: Did you try to make a directive that implement submenu and has '.has-sub' selector?

Answer (score 0):

`routerLink="#"` is invalid.
Either make it a normal `<a href="#">` (without `routerLink`)
or pass a registered route path like

```
<a routerLink="/rootRoute/childRoute"
```

For how to use ther router see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

**update**

To add a click handler only to element with `class="has-sub"` you can use

```
<a class="has-sub" href="#" #li1 (click)="li1.classList.contains('has-sub') ? myClickHandler($event) : false"
```

This way `myClickHandler($event)` is only called when the element has `class="has-sub"`, otherwise `$event.preventDefault()` is called (because of the return value `false`)

Comment: My question was about submenu not invalid parameter.

Comment: I don't see a good reason to discuss more elaborate topics as long as the most basic things are not clear. Why are you using `routerLink`? Do you want to use the router or not?

Comment: When I decide to add route to them. for know it just test. I changed them to the `href`. thank you for respond.

Comment: I updated my answer. Each element needs its unique template variable `#li1`. If you create the `<li>` using `*ngFor` they can all have the same template variable because each element created by `*ngFor` gets its own scope.